# what is better, many repeated rows or increasing the tables?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design

I have a file sharing app. I did not store files in DB. Its just in folders. Those are user uploaded file.
Now each file can be shared with multiple users, say 1 file shared with thousand.
I want to implement this in an easiest way and keeping performance in mind also. Right now i am getting two options in head.

1) table with columns like id, owner,filename, file-path, shared_with **(values sperated by ','. example user1,user2,user3)** , date.

2) a table for each user with columns- id,owner,filename,file-path.

i think 1 option is preferable but getting to know how many files are shared with particular user is difficult. Anyway, i asked cause there could be better answers thank i am thinking to opt those options.
thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your solutions have issues.

With the first option you land up with a comma separated field of users the file is shared with. With this it is just about impossible to efficiently search for the files a user has shared.

With the 2nd you land up with a massive number of tables. If you want to know all the users who a file is shared with you would need to check every one of those tables. Which would be very slow.

Solution is to have a table of files, and a table of who has a file shared with them. On this 2nd table you would have one row per file AND person it is shared with (ie, if a file was shared with 3 people there would be 3 rows for that file on that table).

Something like as follows.

A table of files. One row per file

```
--
-- Table structure for table `filestable`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filestable` (
  `FileId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FilePath` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FileId`),
  KEY `Owner` (`Owner`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Table of users. One row per user

```
--
-- Table structure for table `filesusers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filesusers` (
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Table of file shares. Each file will have one to many rows on here, as will each user. Each file a user has access 2 will have a row

```
--
-- Table structure for table `filesshares`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filesshares` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FileId` (`FileId`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This way you can easily join the tables to find any file a user has access to, or any user a file can be accessed by.

Comment: if i am not wrong u mean some thing like file_details table- id,owner,name,date e.t.c and file_shared id, filename, shared-with. Wright?

Comment: Edited to add some simple suggested table layouts

Comment: now i assume i have 1000 users and 1000 files. According to the example if i am not wrong in understanding, the number of rows in fileshares table will be 1000*1000. which is 10,00,000. So is that not a problem? Is it going to be fine with the increase in numbers?

Comment: No, not a problem. MySQL will cope with that happily (and far larger). Compare that to your solutions where the first would possibly require the shared_with column to be a TEXT type column (taking possibly 10k per row), while your 2nd solution would require 1000 user tables.

Answer (score 1):

Neither option

You already have a file table and a user table. So, you add a file/user table with 2 columns FileID, UserID

Each column is a an foreign key to the respective tables. Both together form the primary key.

You can add other columns to track downloads or datetime stamps etc

Comment: this means each table for each user wright? will than now be an issue if the number of users increases?